# How to use wp_localize_script() variable in js as a variable? (not as string)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've added a field to our wordpress backend where I can write text into it.
(for example "colorVariation + btnVariation) -> That should define a specifc order for the js variables later

I'm able to receive this text in my js file with the wp_localize_script function.

```
  wp_localize_script('wc-product-js', 'script_vars', array(
      'order' => get_field("wc_variation_order"),
      )
  );
```

It seems to be, that this variable get's converted into a string when I try to use the variable in my js file. like that:

```
    var colorVariation = '_red';
    var btnVariation = '_male';        
    var order = script_vars.order;

    var varId = '.variation' + order;
```

My expected output would be ".variation_red_male" but the output is ".variationcolorVariation + btnVariation)

Is there any way to convert this string?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Finally I've found the function by myself. It's eval().

> The eval() function is able to evaluate or executes an argument that
> is passed inside it. If the argument is an expression, this function
> will evaluate the expression and the argument is one or more
> JavaScript statements, eval() executes the statements.

Quote from https://www.codespeedy.com/convert-string-into-variable-name-in-javascript/

```
var colorVariation = '_red';
var btnVariation = '_male';        
var order = script_vars.order;

var varId = '.variation' + eval(order);
```

Comment: Why? / Is there a better way? -Thanks

Comment: Because *any* string will be evaluated as valid code.

Comment: To help you with a better way, please `var_dump()` order within PHP and `console.log()` order from JS console.